# Symfony - which version to get started

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony

now Symfony2 PR4 is released, probably the last one before the official release.
I already have done some tutorials with the latest symfony 1.4 (the complete jobeet tutorial).

My question now: is it better to learn symfony2 before getting closer with 1.4?

if yes, any good sources for learning symfony2? blogs, books, etc..

thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a big part of your answer should be based on your timetable.  if you have to launch your project within the next 3-4 months then I would go with symfony 1.4.

since the GA release of symfony2 is not planned until early next year it would not be good to begin alot of work on that system since things may change and you may have bugs from the code that would be hard to track down.

even though there will be major changes between 1.4 & 2, I don't believe it would be wasted time learning 1.4

for learning symfony2, i would say the two best places would be the symfony site.  [blog here](http://www.symfony-project.org/blog/) and [forum here](http://forum.symfony-project.org/)

Comment: so i don't have to use it for a certain project. i just want to learn this framework to use i for future projects.

Comment: i would recommend learning symfony2 then, although it wouldn't hurt to learn 1.4, nothing written in 1.4 will work in 2